# condition checking according to alert message in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, alert

I have generated two alert messages(Captcha Success & Captcha failed) using

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript.
```

this is my code

```
if (recaptcha.IsValid)
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("captcha", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Captcha Success');</script>");
}
else
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("captcha", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Captcha Failed');</script>");
}
```

now i want to submit my form only captcha success alert is shown.. how can i do that? can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the user from submitting the form using client-side code, you can use something like this:

```
if (recaptcha.IsValid)
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("captcha", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Captcha Success');</script>");
}
else
{
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("captcha", 
        "<script language='javascript'>" +
            "function disableSubmitButton() {" + 
                "document.getElementById('***submitButtonID***').onclick = function(){return false;}" + 
            "}" + 
            "if(window.addEventListener) {" + 
            "    window.addEventListener('load',disableSubmitButton,false);" + 
            "} else {" + 
            "    window.attachEvent('onload',disableSubmitButton);" + 
            "}" +
            "alert('Captcha Failed');" +
        "</script>");
}
```

Note: Remember to replace `***submitButtonID***` with the ID attribute of the submit button.

You can also (more easily) control the button server-side if you don't want to disable it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code inside the if(recaptcha.IsValid) following the pop up script.